# codeception: grabAttributeFrom don't grab

Tags: attributes, acceptance-testing, codeception

I have a command like:
`$name = $I->grabAttributeFrom('#name', 'title');`

This worked fine for a while. But now at retesting it have a wrong behaviour. Any time the grabbed string is empty, even though in attribute 'title' is content.

Yes, I checked the correctness of the css selector and the attribute exist. The test don't fail at this row. It fails if the (empty) string will be compared with an other (`$I->see..`).

Please help if someone knows the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well at this point of time with this much of info,All what i can say is , run a debug.

Before the grabAttributeFrom action, put a pauseExecution and run your code in debug(--debug) mode and when the test halts at this point using firebug check the attribute value in webdriver window and confirm it.

```
$I->pauseExecution();
$I->grabAttributeFrom('#name', 'title');
```

Hope it helps.